# Urban Airship notification does not be shown in android device while message is being received

Tags: android, push-notification, alert, urbanairship.com

I have integrated the urban airship library to an android project.
My problem is that I try to send a message via test push notification in urban airship dashboard.
While I see in logcat -> Received push message: Bundle[{com.urbanairship.push.ALERT=bla blaba etc which means that I receive the message no notification dialog is being shown. What am I doing wrong?
Moreover, I have added the intent receiver class and tried to add a custom notification dialog but nothing worked. On IntentReceiver class the function that is being called is

```
protected void onBackgroundPushReceived(Context context, PushMessage message)
```

but not

```
onPushReceived(Context context, PushMessage message, int notificationId)
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should not need custom notification dialog. Can you share the steps that you took ? Also how are you calling UAirship.takeOff ?

Comment: Well I think that it has everything be set right. By checking the logcat at the IntentReceiver.class I see that the onBackgroundPushReceived(Context context, PushMessage message) is being called and not the onPushReceived(Context context, PushMessage message, int notificationId) which would display the notification. I cannot figure it out why it does happen!! :-( By the way, the urban library android sample worked perfectly..

Comment: Can you share your myApplication class ?

Comment: super.onCreate();


        UAirship.takeOff(this, new UAirship.OnReadyCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onAirshipReady(UAirship airship) {
                // Perform any airship configurations here

                airship.getPushManager().setPushEnabled(true);


            }
        });

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        //Change your UAirship.takeoff() to this :

        //Urban Airship
         AirshipConfigOptions options = AirshipConfigOptions.loadDefaultOptions(getApplicationContext());

        // Take off initializes the services
        UAirship.takeOff(this, options); 
        UAirship.shared().getPushManager().setUserNotificationsEnabled(true);

  //From this

  UAirship.takeOff(this, new UAirship.OnReadyCallback() { 
     @Override public void onAirshipReady(UAirship airship) { 
             // Perform any airship configurations here 
             airship.getPushManager().setPushEnabled(true); 
   });
```

Comment: Thanks you saved my Saturday!! It finally worked!! But why did it worked with your code?Why the urban airship sample did not have problem with my posted take off code?

Comment: I checked the documentation and it specifies to takeoff in the above fashion. Have a good weekend :)

Comment: Correct, user setUserNotificationsEnabled(true) on PushManager needs to be set. It can be set from the onReadyCallback or after takeoff. The only difference between the two is if you want an async takeoff.